# ANDROID STUDIO emulator ERROR x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration

Tags: android

I am a newbie in Android am I have just installed Android Studio on my machine which runs on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I try to run the virtual device I get this error

/home/james/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_2014_API_21 -netspeed full -netdelay none
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: KVM is not installed on this machine (/dev/kvm is missing).

Anyone with a solurion for this?

Comment: You need to [install kvm](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation) and then [follow this guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm)

Comment: Here is Accepted proper answer : 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/564910/kvm-is-not-installed-on-this-machine-dev-kvm-is-missing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution....One must first check whether the machine can support KVM by typing this in the terminal
$ kvm-ok

Output:
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used

After that reboot and enable virtualization in the bios

Comment: kvm-ok is a utility. One must install it first before using the above method.

Answer (score 7):

I too faced the same problem, but it was solved once it by following steps

In android studio Go to Tools--> Android---> AVD Manager

1. For existing emulators in the list Click Edit on the right side corner.
2. In the edit window change the system image
3. Now in the list of images select 'RelaseName' and 'API level' of your choice but 'ABI' should be 'armeabi-v7a'
4. press OK the setting and click finish

my problem is solved with these simple steps

hope this helps to solve your problem

Comment: It has also worked for me, but the emulator closes before performing any operation and gives the following error:-

emulator64-arm: ../../../../../../../src/mesa/drivers/dri/i915/i915_fragprog.c:1273: i915BindProgram: Assertion `p->on_hardware == 0' failed.     

Could you provide me any help for the same?